# Has anyone written down an approach to the Lenard-Magri integrability scheme via algebraic geometry?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, integrable-systems, poisson-geometry

I’ve been thinking about the algebro-geometric meaning of the
Lenard-Magri scheme of getting an integrable system from a pair of
compatible Poisson structures.  I think one might be able
to prove a general result to this effect by considering the
corresponding family of Poisson varieties over the projective line with
an $\mathcal O(1)$-valued Poisson structure, and various subfamilies of symplectic
leaves (carrying an $\mathcal O(-1)$-valued symplectic form).   (It looks like the only assumption needed is that the generic rank of the Poisson structure is constant in the  family.)

**Do you know of any
references where something like this is implemented and/or a general
integrability result in this setting is proved?**

**EDIT:** The condition I suggested in the original question is actually insufficient, and the simplest counterexample is $\mathbb A^2=\mathrm{Spec}\,\Bbbk[x,y]$ with $\{x,y\}_1=1,\ \{x,y\}_2=x$.  So perhaps I should clarify the argument I had in mind for proof of the integrability.  The main statement is as follows:

**Lemma.**  Let $\pi\colon X\to\mathbb P^1$ be a smooth family with an $\mathcal O(-1)$-valued symplectic structure $\omega\colon {\wedge}^2\mathcal T_{X/\mathbb P^1}\to\pi^*\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(-1)$.  Consider $L=\mathrm{Sect}(\mathbb P^1,X)$, the scheme of sections of $\pi$, so that for any scheme $S$, we have a bijection $\mathrm{Hom}(S,L)\overset\sim\to \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb P^1}(\mathbb P^1\times S,X)$ functorial in $S$. (It exists by virtue of $\mathbb P^1$ being proper.) Then for any $\lambda\in\mathbb P^1$, the image of $L$ in $X_\lambda:=X\times_{\mathbb P^1}\{\lambda\}$ Is a smooth Lagrangian subvariety.

I still think this lemma is true, and it can be proved using Serre duality.  Furthermore, by definition, a pair of compatible Poisson brackets on $Y$ give an $\mathcal O(1)$-valued fiberwise Poisson structure on the trivial family $Y \times\mathbb P^1 \to\mathbb P^1$, which can be restricted to subfamily of symplectic leaves through a given point, ***provided that these leaves all have the same dimension***. However, it might happen, as in the example above, that there is *no* point with such property!  One should therefore add this additional assumption in the original integrability criterion.